# How to calculate time difference automatically in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, time, xampp

I have a database table. The creation query is listed as below.

```
CREATE TABLE `prime_clock` (
  `stage` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_time` time NOT NULL,
  `end_time` time NOT NULL,
  `difference` time NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Consider I have a sample entry as

```
INSERT INTO `prime_clock` (`stage`, `name`, `start_time`, `end_time`, `difference`) VALUES
(1, 'fff', '12:33:00', '13:00:00', '00:00:00');
```

For primary key I used

```
ALTER TABLE `prime_clock`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`stage`);
```

Now the question is How do I find duration between the start and end time; I.e. *end_time* - *start_time* and store in *difference* **automatically** as add a new row or make a modification in start time or end time.

Also, I can do it manually using

```
UPDATE `prime_clock` SET `difference`=TIMEDIFF(`end_time`,`start_time`) WHERE 1
```

Comment: I think you want to use calculated columns

Comment: While [13.1.18.8 CREATE TABLE and Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) is an option, the following limitation must be considered, given its requirement: `For INSERT, REPLACE, and UPDATE, if a generated column is inserted into, replaced, or updated explicitly, the only permitted value is DEFAULT.`. Another option is to use triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go ahead with one of the following approaches:

1. *Generated columns (explained [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)):* You can define the table as follows:

   `CREATE TABLE prime_clock (
   stage int(11) NOT NULL,
   name varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   start_time time NOT NULL,
   end_time time NOT NULL,
   difference time AS TIMEDIFF(end_time, start_time) STORED
   ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`
2. *Trigger:* You can write a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger that calculates `difference` for every inserted row, e.g.:

   `DELIMITER //
   CREATE TRIGGER calculate_difference
   BEFORE INSERT
      ON table FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
      SET NEW.difference = TIMEDIFF(end_time, start_time);
   END; //
   DELIMITER ;`

Comment: I used your 1st approach with this correction.
difference time AS (TIMEDIFF(end_time, start_time))

This solves the problem at the time of insertion.

But at the time of update of fields (i.e. start_time or end_time), the difference is not updated automatically.

Comment: @AbhijitSrivastava I have added `STORED` to generated column definition in my answer, try now?

Comment: Actually, i just figured out that approach works. PhpMyAdmin was too outdated that we need to refresh to see the effects.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45233939/mysql-xampp-server-known-error-in-time-difference-on-bigrock

could you check this.